# JQuery popup works on load, but then reloads

Tags: jquery

I am trying to make a simple popup without extensions to jquery. The popup load on page load like it should, but the problem I am having is making some way to close the popup without it automatically re-initating when I do so.Which it currently does, because it is attached to $(document).ready(. Thanks :)

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#page').animate({"opacity":"0.4"});
 $('#popup').delay(300).fadeIn('slow');

$('#close').click( function() {
    $('#page').animate({"opacity":"1"});
 $('#popup').fadeOut('fast');
})
})
```

Comment: with the above code, it fires a second time after the ('#close').click function is called

Comment: The code looks ok but it also depends on what the type of elements you are using for #close, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If #close is a link with href, you may try this:

```
 $('#close').click( function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     $('#page').animate({"opacity":"1"});
     $('#popup').fadeOut('fast');
 });
```